# Pass HTML Element Values Created On Client Side Via JS To Server Side (ASP.Net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ASP.NET with Bootstrap to create a website.

Inside the .APSX HTML File I have a **JavaScript function that adds additional Rows to the HTML Table containing TextAreas**.

Now the problem is - **How do I process TextArea data from newly created Rows on the server side?**

As I've researched - whatever is created on Client Side dynamically via JavaScript cannot be "seen" on the server side.

Furthermore, all the additionally added rows are lost on asp:button Click event.

I've read that you can somehow pass JS data to Server side using JSON, but I'm not familiar with either of them (the JS code I'm using was found on the Internet).

```
<table id="myTable" class="table" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:90%;">
                <textarea rows="2" name="name" style="width:100%;" runat="server"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%;"> <a class="deleteRow" style="width:100%;"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function() {

            counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td style="width:90%;"><textarea rows="2" name="name" style="width:100%;" runat="server"></textarea></td>';

            cols += '<td style="width:10%;"><input type="button" style="width:100%;" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            if (counter == 20) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
            $("table.table").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        });

        $("table.table").on("change", 'input[name^="price"]', function(event) {
            calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
            calculateGrandTotal();
        });

        $("table.table").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            calculateGrandTotal();

            counter -= 1
            $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
        });
    });

    function calculateRow(row) {
        var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

    }
</script>
```

Could I perhaps somehow Request the Table on server side and then itterate through it?

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating a form?

Comment: Indeed. In addition, you will need to give your textareas different names. Or, sure, if you want to do it the hard way, AJAX.

Comment: Are there any decent alternatives?  There's asp:Table, but there's ahrdly any information on it online (seems to be outdated). Then There's GridView, but it needs DataSource to function, but in my case I want client to input their data.

Comment: `asp:table` (and other things starting with `asp:`) are server-side elements that cannot be created client-side. So that's a dead end. For user input, use a control that can handle user input; `<input>`, `<textarea>` and so on, and retrieve the posted data server-side through `Request.Form`. For extra (non-user-input) HTML markup, make sure that the server side knows what markup was created; for example put info explicitly in a hidden `<input>` that the server side can parse and act upon.